# What is meant by 'centering quality'?

Tags: lens, terminology, lens-design

I'm reading lens reviews and I have encountered the term 'centering quality' a few times (e.g. http://www.photozone.de/sony_nex/720-sony50f18nex?start=1).

What does this term mean? What are the factors that influence the effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Centering quality" is the degree to which the lens produces symmetrical focusing performance in all radial directions from the centre.That is, focus or resolution may change as you progress along a radial line from the centre, but in a perfectly centred  lens the performance along all radial paths will be equal.

There's a reasonably good discussion here - [Do it yourself centering sanity check](http://forum.photozone.de/index.php?/topic/830-do-it-yourself-centering-sanity-check/) .
 The questions and answers are arguably as useful as the actual article.
  The site provides a very simple template which can be printed to assist testing. 
In each test image 4 x black & white boundaries are arranged radially and the user assesses how sharp they are relatively.